# Putting doc-strings on data vars, is it considered idiomatic?

Tags: documentation, clojure

So I have defined some vars to hold state data in my clojure code. I have just discovered I can add a doc-string to those vars e.g.:

```
(def ^{:doc "Documentation for *my-var*"}
        *my-var*)
```

That lets me call `(doc *my-var*)` at the REPL. This seems like a valid and useful thing to do but it doesn't seem like common practice in the (limited) code I have read.

Is this considered idiomatic clojure?

Comment: +1 for the idea; out of curiosity: who is that documentation for ? who's supposed to be reading it ?

Comment: I am now pretty much a convert to the idea that I need to write documentation for the the "future me".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Also used in Clojure namespaces (like clojure.pprint):

```
(def
 ^{:doc "The base to use for printing integers and rationals."
   :added "1.2"}
 *print-base* 10)
```

You may wan't to use a convenience macro from clojure.contrib.def:

```
(defvar *my-var*
  nil
  "Documentation for *my-var*")
```

Comment: I think there was a patch applied recently, which brings docstring support to "native" `def`.

Answer (score 19):

Since clojure 1.3, `def` has allowed an optional docstring.

```
(def *my-var*
  "My var does cool things (it really doesn't)."
  nil)
```